# navigationController popToRootViewController and viewWillDisappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a simple navigation hierarchy:

```
Controller 1 > Controller 2 > Controller 3
```

Each controller contains a reference (`@property (nonatomic, assign) ...`) to it's child and parent.

My viewWillDisappear looks something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    if (![self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self]) {
        // View has been popped! Important to distinguish between view popping and tab switching.
        // If parent view controller is active, pass a message.
        if (_refParentViewController && !_isSearchViewController) {
            _refParentViewController.valueX = @"xyz";
        }
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Now, there's a case where following statement is executed (by Controller 1):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

As a result, i get a crash because _refParentViewController is a deallocated instance (at this point). How can i check whether _refParentViewController is valid? I thought that the view controllers/views will get destroyed in order but it appears that there isn't any specific order and Controller 2 is destroyed before Controller 3.

I can check `retainCount` but i'm not sure if that's a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can check retainCount but i'm not
>   sure if that's a good idea.

It is a horrible idea;  retainCount is useless, don't call it.  And note that retainCount can *never* return 0;  it can't be used to know if an object is deallocated or not.

If both your parent and child properties are `assign`, then who is responsible for retaining the view controller?  You need a `retain` that spans the expected lifespan of the parent/child properties.

I would suggest that you make the `child` property `retain` and leave the parent property as `assign`.  You also need to make sure that when you set the `child` to `nil` (which, with a `retain` property will `release` it *as long as you go through the property's setter*) that you first set the child's `parent` property to `nil`.